# Is there a way to pass dynamic arguments to an array.filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet of data and wish to filter it quickly.

I have got a working solution with

```js
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  if(data[i][4] == year && data[i][0] == month && data[i][1] == day){
    result.push({initials: data[i][7], name: data[i][3], reg: data[i][5], id: 
    data[i][8]});
  }
}
```

Is there a way to either speed this up or use array.filter with dynamic inputs.
e.g. this non-working code where in production year, month and day would dynamically be called in the function.

```js
var year = "Year 14";
var month = 2;
var day = 28;
var data = studentsWS.getDataRange().getValues();
var filteredData = data.filter(
  function (row){
    return row[4] == year && row[0] == month && row[1] == day
  }
);
```

Comment: *"e.g. this non-working code"* how/why is this code not working? do you get any errors?

Comment: What is not working about your attempt? It works for me.

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad using something new to me in JavaScript. Have always used the for loop in JS.  When I was in the GAS editor year, month and day weren't highlighting blue as existing variables so thought it wasn't working. I just had year, month and day that weren't giving a result. Cheers all